# SQL query price retrieval

Tags: mysql, sql

I got 2 tables storing prices of the product.

The main table is `Product` which has all the product details.

The price of the products is being stored in two different tables with the following structures:

- **variant:** `p_id`, `price`.
- **advance_price:** `p_id`, `price`.

Now I want to merge those tables to get all the prices of the product.

**Note**: one product has price in either `variant` table or `advance_price` table. Not is both table.

I am looking for the result like this:

```
product.id, price
```

(this can be from `variant` table or `advance_price` table)

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is to `COALESCE()` the prices from the two tables, with appropriate joins:

```
SELECT
  Product.p_id,
  COLAESCE(variant.price, advance_price.price) AS price
FROM
  Product
  LEFT JOIN variant ON Product.p_id = variant.p_id
  LEFT JOIN advance_price ON Product.p_id = advance_price.p_id
```

`COALESCE()` will take the first non-null value in its arguments.  `LEFT JOIN` is used in case no record exists in the `variant` or `advance_price` tables for a given `p_id`.